# Take user to custom page

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, custom-url

I want to implement a `custom-url` like this....
where once the user type
***http://localhost/website/username*** it would take the user to a customize page where only information pertaining to the user is shown. I have been able to figure out the url like this

```
 Public sUsername = ""
```

***http://localhost/website/<%= sUsername %>***
But I am stuck on how I would apply this on the landing page? Is the landing page going to be Default.aspx?

Comment: Have you looked at routing: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668201%28v=vs.140%29.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Until the user is registered, you can't do anything. Beyond this, you will most likely use either a login or cookies (cookies fail at some time).

If you are asking how to make a friendly URL, the answer is URL rewriting. Scott Guthrie wrote about it years ago (and the sample is in VB.NET).

http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/tip-trick-url-rewriting-with-asp-net

Routing is also a possibility:http://www.asp.net/web-forms/overview/routing

NOTE: I have aimed at ASP.NET WebForms, but the same concepts can be applied to ASP.NET MVC

Comment: what I meant is adding a variable to the default page like http://localhost/website/variable ...... the variable would be used as a parameter in opening the users custom page.....